# Remove duplicate arrays in a ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, duplicates

Is there a way to remove duplicates arrays in an `ArrayList`?
I tried to convert the `ArrayList` into a `HashSet` and back to remove the duplicate arrays.
But this won't work:

```
ArrayList<int[]> mylist = new ArrayList<int[]>(); 

mylist.add(new int[]{1,2});
mylist.add(new int[]{2,2}); // Duplicate
mylist.add(new int[]{2,2}); // Duplicate
```

Before:

```
{{1,2},{2,2},{2,2}}
```

After:

```
{{1,2},{2,2}}
```

Comment: What defines a duplicate? '2' or `int[]{2,2}`?

Comment: Check if your Arraylist contains an Array before adding it

Comment: extend ArrayList and override add/addAll methods by checking first if the new item already exists in the list

Comment: @xgeorgekx Ok, I gonna try this out using a hashCode based on the value (@laune ´s idea)

Comment: http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/12/how-to-remove-duplicates-elements-from-ArrayList-Java.html

Comment: HashSets don't work for arrays. But they do work for ArrayList. So why don't you use `HashSet<ArrayList<Integer>>` instead of `ArrayList<int[]>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different array objects have different hashCode() values even if their contents are equal.

Offhand, I can't think of anything better than to wrap the arrays into a class and to hash all wrapped arrays using a hashCode based on the value and the Arrays.equals as an equals.

This would be O(n) as opposed to searching for duplicates in a nested loop (O(n^2)).

Comment: I am gonna check with Arrays.equals a duplicate before adding it. Also thanks to @xgerogekx.

Comment: Preventing the evil is alway best ;-) Although, it'll be costly and costlier with increasing list length.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done with an `ArrayList`, this could be done with a [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) and a custom [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) implementation which is able to accurately compare the `int[]` objects.

For example:

```
public final class IntArrayComparator implements Comparator<int[]>
{
    public int compare(int[] a, int[] b)
    {
        if (a == null)
            return b == null ? 0 : 1;

        if (a.length != b.length)
            return a.length - b.length;

        for (int i=0; i<a.length; ++i)
        {
            final int diff = a[i] - b[i];
            if (diff != 0)
                return diff;
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```